# How is this equation derived for a low pass filter?

Tags: capacitor, resistors

[image]

[image]

How’s the second line of the equation derived from the Kirchhoff law’s equation in the first line?

If then, how was the equation in the third line derived?

I’m very confused by the steps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple KCL equation:
$$
\frac{V_{in}-V_{o}}{R} = i(t) 
$$

and since \$V_o\$ is an open, the whole current flows into the capacitor, and we know that the current through the capacitor is:
$$
i(t) = i_c(t) = C\frac{dV_o}{dt} 
$$
and we use \$dV_o\$ in the numerator because there's a voltage \$V_o\$ across this capacitor.

Comment: Is there a reason why Vo is open? Why won’t no current flow to Vo?

Comment: Because there is no load on Vo.  It is just sitting there, with no resistor to GND, or an opamp input, or even the high impedance of a scope input.  All of the current through R ahs to go somewhere that constitutes a return path to the Vin source, and the schematic shows nothing but C.

Comment: @SwiftEnthusiast this is where loading becomes important. If there's a resistive load, the frequency response of your RC LPF would change. The only way to approximate, in reality, the schematic in your question to connect \$V_o\$ to a high impedance node.

Answer (score 2):

Since C is connected between ground and `Vo`,`Vo` is the same as `Vc`.

And the voltage `Vr` over the resistor is, according to Ohm´s law, `Vr=I*R`.